# Is there a way to use individual DSA key-pairs for Apache (WebDAV) Authentication?

Tags: apache-2.2, webdav

I'm basically looking for a way to allow for secure, but password-less authentication to SVN through WebDAV (I would rather not use svn+ssh.)  I know this is possible with SSH, is it possible with Apache Authentication too?

Answer (score 1):

[Something like this?](http://www.impetus.us/~rjmooney/projects/misc/clientcertauth.html) The page looks pretty old though...

Comment: That looks like it's just HTTPS where the client already has the certificate.  I'm looking for something to identify and authenticate each individual user.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. SSL cert auth is the only way that i know of.

Comment: @Nate Wagar, by following the above you would issue a unique key and certificate each user.  Though I would suggest you use something like TinyCA (http://tinyca.sm-zone.net/) instead of creating all the certs manually.

Comment: See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol